# How to put references within a section

Tags: biblatex, cross-referencing

I couldn't find a solution to this issue, so I'm asking a new question.
I have an article (a thesis proposal) and I need the references to appear within a section (the last one). I'm using biblatex and the command

```
\printbibliography
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not very obvious what you want to achieve, and you should show a proper minimal example alongside your questions. However:

Do you mean you want to have another title for the references? Then use

```
\printbibliography[title=My Title]
```

Do you want the references to be a subheading of the last section? Then use

```
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
```

If it is neither of those, I have no clue what you mean and you should direly prepare a minimal working example.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for not being totally clear. I wanted to achieve the second thing (and it worked!).